# Can't install Banshee

Tags: banshee, package-management

This is what I get when I try to install Banshee:

```
sudo apt-get install banshee
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 banshee : Depends: libdbus-glib1.0-cil (>= 0.5) but it is not installable
           Depends: libdbus1.0-cil (>= 0.7) but it is not installable
           Recommends: banshee-extension-soundmenu (= 2.3.1+git20111114.r1.aea7412-0ubuntu1+maverick) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried to search for "how to fix broken packages" posts, but none of them helped. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using some PPAs? What happens when you open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed the banshee 2.3.1 ppa for ubuntu maverick meerkat? Info you probably should have included in your question, rather than let the detectives figure it out :)

> = 2.3.1+git20111114.r1.aea7412-0ubuntu1+maverick

The simplest way of dealing it would be to remove the offending repository from your '/etc/apt/sources.list.d'. Then, add the following ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
```

After you've done that,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil
```

(they're available on the aforementioned ppa). Then, you can re-add the daily ppa,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/banshee-daily;sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and you can install the soundmenu extension from there.

ps. I don't know if removing the unstable ppa is strictly necessary -- you'll probably get away with just adding the stable ppa and installing the libdbus* dependencies from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had no idea the daily repository could conflict with the stable one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Still the same problem afterdoing that? Download the missing dependencies from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), install them, and try again.